# Using a word boundary, how to match a string of numbers unless there is a period before the numbers?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I am trying to match a set of numbers that refer to items.
The items may be separated by linebreak, a comma, a colon, a dash or a space. 
The items would not be separated by a period or an @ sign.

We were using `\b` to denote the start of the items, but have found this to capture all sorts of undesired matches, such as `reallythisurl@6001999` and `reallythis.6001999`

We tried the negative lookahead: `\b(?!\.)(601999)`  `\b(?!\@)(601999)`

But this did not stop from matching numbers that came after a period or an `@`

Comment: we don't have to use the word boundary if there is another way to do this.  thanks!!

Comment: Please include sample data which you are trying to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add negative lookbehind: `(?<![@.])\b\d+`

`(?<![@.])` - assures that what preceeds is not `@` or `.`

`\b` - word boudnary

`\d+` - one or more digits

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NGCEFg/1)